# Simple XML namespace warning

Tags: php, namespaces, simplexml

I am trying to parse the following XML using simplexml...

http://datapoint.metoffice.gov.uk/public/data/txt/wxfcs/regionalforecast/xml/500?key=ed47ad61-5033-48c8-bf7c-6c4c0b17c3f3

but as soon as I add the line...

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://datapoint.metoffice.gov.uk/public/data/txt/wxfcs/regionalforecast/xml/500?key=ed47ad61-5033-48c8-bf7c-6c4c0b17c3f3');
```

I get and error like

```
namespace warning : xmlns: URI www.metoffice.gov.uk/xml/metoRegionalFcst is not absolute
```

I can't seem to work out how to get around this problem.

Comment: The namespace (xmlns) URI needs to have `http://` before it to make it absolute.

Comment: Ok thanks, but seeing as i have zero control of the XML file, is there any way round it for me?

Comment: Since it says "warning", are you sure that this is actually a problem? i.e. does it stop the rest of the script running?

Answer (score 14):

just add @ before  simplexml_load_file

like

$xml = @simplexml_load_file('http://datapoint.metoffice.gov.uk/public/data/txt/wxfcs/regionalforecast/xml/500?key=ed47ad61-5033-48c8-bf7c-6c4c0b17c3f3');

Comment: This does not resolve the problem. A solution is needed to parse the xml.

Comment: This did work for me. Why? What is magical about that @ before the function call? Oh, never mind. I did some searching and found that @ simply silences errors and warnings that the function may cause.

Answer (score 0):

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$xml = simplexml_load_file($file->getTempName());


us3.php.net/manual/es/function.simplexml-load-file.php
us3.php.net/manual/es/function.libxml-use-internal-errors.php
us3.php.net/manual/es/simplexml.examples-errors.php
```

Comment: Could you please explain how does it answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, As this is only a warning from PHP and you can suppress it by doing any method that works for you.

It may be one of them

1.`@simplexml_load_string($response)`:` PHP supports one error control operator: the at sign (@) for more https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php.

2.`simplexml_load_string($response,'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOWARNING);`
https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/sdk-php/issues/135

Answer (score 0):

If it help you can do the next thing

```
// Set the url of your XML file

 $XmlPath = resource_path('xml/').'mifile.xml';

//Parse the XML file, dont forget use the "Nowarning lib" and "Compact" those are so usefull

 $Codes = simplexml_load_file ( $XmlPath , 'SimpleXMLElement' , LIBXML_NOWARNING | LIBXML_COMPACT   , null , false );
```